# ParseFacebookUtilsV4, Swift and CocoaPods: unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm developing an iOS App using XCode 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t) and Swift 2.0 that use Parse, Facebook and Google Maps. This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'SWRevealViewController'
```

I tried to follow the Parse guide (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-log-in-amp-sign-up) but I receive this error

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'PFFacebookUtils'
```

This is my Bridging Header

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <SWRevealViewController/SWRevealViewController.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import **ParseFacebookUtilsV4** in your code

```
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
```

this worked for me

Comment: I did and I didn't update my answer, but it is the way!

Answer (score 1):

Under your project's build settings, make sure that in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, your Objective-C Bridging Header path is set to yourProjectName/nameOfYourBridgingHeader.h

Comment: Hi @Grant Park. Yes, I did. The problem, I think is "use_frameworks!"

Comment: I believe Parse still has issues with Swift 2.0, they will probably release an SDK to support this soon.